# Can't set local image as URL in React

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React using the create-react-app demo app. I am trying to edit it to show a picture like so:

```
    <img className="media-object" width="75" height="75" src={"./img/initials.jpg"}>
```

I also tried:

```
<img className="media-object" width="75" height="75" src={require('./img/initials.jpg')}>
```

But the image is not loaded.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: remove the `.` from `"./img/initials.jpg"`

Comment: Where is your image stored and where is your page stored? The first option should work. Don't use `require`.

Comment: Removing the dot didn't help. Everything is stored locally. I have the code under src folder and in the src folder I have an img folder with the initials.jpg image.

Comment: In create-react-app, you have to store your images in the `/public` directory. Move your `/img` directory into public and then your relative paths should work.

Comment: Wow, thanks Chase. It's a shame you answered as a comment - I can't mark your answer as the correct one.

Comment: @gfels Just moved my comment to an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In create-react-app, [you have to store your images in the `/public` directory](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#when-to-use-the-public-folder). Move your `/img` directory into `/public` and then your relative paths should work.