# CSS backgrounds in react

Tags: css, reactjs

so i'm in the process of learning react and to do so i'm trying to convert my personal webpage to use it.. But i've hit a wall. Before I had a background image on my home page that took up 100% width and 80% height. But when I try to do that in react it's not showing my image. Here is my code.

```
body,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;}
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    color: #777;
    line-height: 1.8;
    margin: 0;
}

/* Create a Parallax Effect */
.bgimg-1, .bgimg-2, .bgimg-3 {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}

.bgimg-1 {
    background-image: url('../images/haha.jpg');
    min-height: 80%;
}

#homeTest {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

and on the react side i'm just doing:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './css/w3.css';
import './css/landing.css'
class Landing extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="bgimg-1" id="home">
        <div  id="homeText">
          <h1>David Dennis <small>Im here to create meaningful and lasting software</small>
            <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCun833t1bRiYlpoRAkg0S1g?view_as=subscriber">
              <button class="btn draw-border" >Subscribe on YouTube</button></a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is most likely with the image URL. What's your build setup? Is it create-react-app, or a custom config?

Comment: I used  create-react-app to build my project.  But the image is in the folder ans when I dumb down the CSS and just add a <h1> tag with the bg image it works.

Comment: @DavidDennis Where is you `image` folder located? It should be in the `public` directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't set local image as URL in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49517840/cant-set-local-image-as-url-in-react)

Comment: I tried to create a image folder under public and reference it like:     background-image: url('./images/landingpage.jpg');
with no luck